# C++ ostream_withassign with << operator compile error

Tags: c++, solaris

I'm working on some legacy code with an old Solaris compiler on Solaris 10 (no new fangled C++0x here ;-)

> -bash-3.2$ CC -V
>
> CC: Sun C++ 5.12 SunOS_sparc 2011/11/16

I've got a 3rd party dictionary class with an iterator

```
template<K, V>
class DictIterator
{
    public:
        DictIterator(TheDictClass<K, V>& collection);
        K key() const;
        V value() const;
        // advance the iterator. return true if iterator points to a valid item
        bool operator()();
    ...
};
```

My code is supposed to go through each item in the dictionary but has a compile error that I can't explain:

```
DictIterator iterator(theDictionary);
while(iterator())
{
    cout << iterator.key(); 
}
```

Fails with `"filename.cc", line 42: Error: The operation "ostream_withassign<<Key" is illegal.`

But this version works:

```
DictIterator iterator(theDictionary);
while(iterator())
{
    Key key(iterator.key());
    cout << key; 
}
```

Obviously I've got a workaround but I thought that since `DictIterator.key()` returns a `K` (not a reference), the two snippets were pretty similar. Can anyone let me know what weird corner of C++ I've just bumped into?

edit: To answer comments, `<<` is overridden `ostream& operator(ostream &, Key&);`

Comment: `DictIterator` is a class template, so this makes no sense without more context: `DictIterator iterator(theDictionary);`. Also `key()` is private.

Comment: Please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us.

Comment: Did you define/overload the << operator for Key ?

Comment: `Key&` should be `const Key&`.

Comment: @n.m. I'm working with legacy code, and in the legacy code it isn't const. If you can make an answer out of why it has to be const then I'm all ears ;-)

Comment: A temporary cannot be passed by non-const reference. There is about a zillion duplicates on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `operator<<` takes its right argument by non-const lvalue reference. This means that temporaries cannot be bound to this argument.

The `key()` method returns a temporary. Only by creating a local variable can you turn this temporary into a variable that the lvalue reference can bind to.

Changing the argument of the operator to a `const Key&` solves this problem because a const lvalue reference can bind to temporaries. This should be a minimally invasive and safe change - it could only fail to work if the output operator used non-const functionality of the object being written, which would be a big red flag in itself. However, if the existing code is not const-correct (i.e. member functions that do not modify their objects are not consistently marked as `const`), this may lead to a long tail of fixing such const-correctness violations.